# Reading properties file (WildFly on Unx)

Tags: unix, properties, wildfly

I have problem with reading properties file on Unix machine.
All working fine on Windows.

More details:

- WildFlie 8 server,
- application is ear file,
- properties file and java class are in same package,
- properties and java class are in WAR file which is in EAR file.

The code below contains two methods both working correct on Windows but none of them 
working on Unix.
Why?

```
package com.mycode.utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LoadMessageProperty {

    public static final String MESSAGE = "messages.properties"; 
    private static final Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(LoadMessageProperty.class.getName());

    public String getMessage(String key) {
        logger.debug("getMessage(key["+key+"]) BEGIN");
        String value = null;
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {

            input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(MESSAGE);
            if (input == null) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + MESSAGE);
            } else {
                prop.load(input);
                value = prop.getProperty(key);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error(e);
                }
            }
        }

        logger.debug("getMessage(key["+key+"]) END");
        return value;
    }

    public String getMessageBundle(String key){
        ResourceBundle properties;
        String value = "";
        properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.mycode.utils.messages");
        value = properties.getString(key);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error? There's not much to go on since you don't describe the issue you're having.

Comment: Also what java version are you running on each?

Comment: In both methods I get null:
- 'input' in 'getMessage' is null,
- properties in 'getMessageBundle' is null.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figure it out.
I needed to add

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
    </resource>         
</resources>
```

to my pom.xml